# What's the best way to refactor a database and its data? (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, version-control, migration

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with structural as well as data concerned changes within migrations in Laravel 5.2.
At the moment I just change the existing data after applying structural changes to the database.
But that seems to collide with the version controlled code.

### A simple example

A column `owner_id` should be added to the `teams` table. Simple migration, no problem. Afterwards, all existing teams should get such an id. Therefore I put this in the migration, too:

```
foreach ($teams as $team) {
    // get the first user of this team over a many-to-many-relationship-table `team_user`
    $team->owner_id = $team->users->first()->id;
    ...
}
```

At the first glance that works fine.

After a few days and commits, I decide to add a pivot column `role` in the mentioned relation table. I add the migration and in the team model I put something like this:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(...)->withPivot('role');
}
```

### The resulting problem

If I want to completely refresh my local database now, I'll get an error in the first migration. That's because it called $team->users, but in this state of the database the `role` isn't available yet and so the method call fails. It's like a shift between version control and database migrations.

Is there a clean solution for this?

Big thanks in advance, 
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually migrating is DDL (data definition language) and seeding is DML (data manipulation language).

Migrating database tables is a matter of order. You cannot add code which depends on some DDL, which may be executed before those DDL are run.

Another thing you have to consider is: migrations are not the place to do data seeding, modification, manipulation, because seeding may require ALL data definition is done before you start seeding. That's why Laravel has data seeding.

So, there is no difference between seeding, fixing nor changing data, it's all DML. You can do it in your migrations, it's not forbidden, but in those you have to be very careful by undoing (on down) every single step you took in the `up` method. But sometimes it is too hard to **manipulate back your data**.

Your problem is that you are trying to access some data, via relations, which is not ready (or done, or seeded) yet, because a migration which would do that were not run yet. So you have a conflict between DDL and DML, which would not occur if you treated them separately.

Usually data seeding is done only for testing, but if you really need it you can do something like this in your seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (app()->environment('testing')) {
            $this->call(TestingSeeders::class);
        }

        $this->call(ProductionReadySeeders::class);
    }
}
```

Or you can just create a command to seed your data:

```
Artisan::command('app:seed', function ($email)
{
    // Do whatever you need to seed your database tables
});
```

And run with

```
php artisan app:seed
```

If you want to make sure everyone who gets a new version if your app also get the correct data, you can use Composer post execution commands to do so:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
   "php artisan optimize",
   "php artisan migrate --force",
   "php artisan app:seed" 
],

"post-update-cmd": [
   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
     "php artisan optimize",
     "php artisan migrate --force", 
     "php artisan app:seed"
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Seeding isn't the problem, in my local environment all seeds are applied after the migrations and work very well. But on production I need to change already existing data to match a new database structure. How would I go about this?

Comment: There is no difference between seeding, fixing nor changing data, it's all DML. You can do it in your migrations, it's not forbidden, but in those you have to be very careful by undoing (on down) every single step you took in the `up` method. But sometimes it is too hard to **manipulate back your data**.

Your problem is that you are trying to access some data, via relations, which is not ready (or done, or seeded) yet, because a migration which would do that was not run yet. So you have a conflict between DDL and DML, which would not occur if you treated them separately.

Comment: Ok, so maybe it would be a solution to put all the "changing existing data" logic into a separate artisan command? Then one could deploy on production, run the migration and afterwards run the command. But then everyone who wants to checkout a new feature would need to run this command after the migration, too. And when there isn't only one migration, he would have to make sure that he runs multiple such commands, wouldn't he? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah, that may be a problem but you have ways of ensuring everyone gets the proper data changed the way it should. Edited to show one way, there are many others.

Comment: Alright, thanks again, I'll see what I can achieve. What do you think about the possibility to just use clean database queries to change existing data? That would separate it from the app code but ensure that after every migration the database is in the planned state for every developer. This would bring DML and DDL closer together but maybe that's ok for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: The only way I see you not having trouble with this thing in the future is always have your data related migrations as last migration to be executed. That may work, but, if, again, you create some data, add some relations to models, and expect the data to be there on a new migrate:reset, if the data migration is not the last one, you will risk having the very same problem.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the moved/changed data to be there on a reset, I would only want that the migrations pass without an error because a method from the app code is no longer available. I'll try to run all dml operations after the migrations, hope that works. Thanks a lot for your patience and help!